# ASP.NET Core - Static Files Not Found By Kestrel Behind Apache Reverse Proxy on Particular Device

Tags: apache, embedded-linux, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-3.1, imx6

I have developed a simple ASP.Net Core Razor pages app that runs OK, deployed standalone, on an iMX6ULL development board running an Apache reverse proxy server.  However, when I deploy the exact same app onto a different development board (same processor just made by a different company), the app appears to run OK but static content inside the 'wwwroot' folder is not found.

I have checked the web and content root paths when the app is running and they match where the publish folder is copied in both device file systems.  As the source code for the app is unchanged, I am sure it must be something in the difference between the Apache and/or OS setup between the two devices but for the life of me, I cannot find/think what that is!! Does anyone have any ideas?  I am pulling my hair out :(

If it helps, httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf are the same on both devices, with Apache listening on 80 and forwarding to 5000 where the ASP.Net Core app tells me it's listening.  Is it possible that there is a conflict on this port?  I have tried 5050 but with the same result...

Comment: Did you solve that?